# Similar questions on same topic, mark as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, homework

[This](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/171026/mj13) user has asked 3 very similar questions in a short span of time (one of which was an exact duplicate of another older question which I answered).

[image]

All three questions seem to variations in the same series of exercises:

[image]
[image]

He does not seem to be learning from the answers as on each question he asks how to approach the problem, then someone solves it for him, and he moves to the next one.

So, would it be reasonable to close the questions or are those legitimate questions for EE.SE?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Close 'em. They are "homework questions" (whether or not they are actual homework), which is a category that is of dubious long-term value to the site in general.